# PHP SSI with NGINX

Tags: php, nginx, server-side-includes

I've got a really old website I'd like try running on NGINX instead of Apache. This site consists of many flat HTML files with sporadic PHP SSIs, such as:

```
<!--#include virtual="/some_file.php" -->
```

How does does the NGINX [HttpSsiModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSsiModule) handle these includes when they're dynamic? In the module docs, it says:

```
The distinction between "file" and "virtual" is mostly historical. "file" is
the same as "virtual" with implied "wait" option.
```

This doesn't get into how I am supposed to configure the PHP execution. Using the above `#include`, is the implication here that I am supposed to set up a `location` that matches `/some_file.php` and is configured to fastcgi over to php-fpm (or something else like that)?

Comment: I missed a line in the docs that says: `The target of "file" or "virtual" must be a location in the server configuration.`

Comment: Once you have it working, be sure to come back and answer your own question!

Comment: Deleted my answer as I though this was Apache specific but it's not.